# Issue When trying to use port forwarding to expose PRTG Network Monitor

Tags: ssl

I am currently trying to expose our PRTG network monitor to the web so that we can monitor the network using the PRTG app and without having to remote in to a PC on the network. I have tried to use port forwarding on our Draytek Vigor3900 firewall, which works perfectly fine when we exposed our KMV Masterview. 
The Masterview was already using port 443 for the SSL connection, I have set the Network Monitor to listen on port 7342.

[image: PRTG Webserver Setup]

I have set up the port forwarding as follows

[image: Port Forward Setup]

This is the exact same setup as the other port forward, the only difference is the public port it uses, and the private port the SSL uses. I have looked up online and found that there should be no issues with changing the SSL port as long as the port forward on the firewall is trying to listen to the same private port, but when I try to open the page by going to ''it just says that the web page is not available. I also know that the network monitor is working perfectly fine when trying to access it internally.

Help with this would be much appreciated, any additional info can be given if needed.

Comment: Where are you configuring the port forwarding actually? And how are you accessing it? For external access have you already opened the port 11001 on firewall?

Comment: Hi, I am configuring it on the Port redirection section on the firewall, and I am accessing it via chrome. I have only opened 11000, not 11001. Thanks

Comment: But if I understand it correctly, you are forwarding port 11001. So it needs to be open in the firewall too. You can also see your firewalls log for more info. And I actually wanted to know, externally with which address/hostname you are using. I mean, you can not test it internally I suppose.

Comment: Yeah I have opened it up in the firewall, and the firewall logs don't seem to give me much info, when I try to access it I get the following error
"Dump Connection Name done, Total 0 Connections added in whack" Although it only seems to come up every few times I refresh so i'm not 100% sure if it has any relevance... No other logs are coming up when I attempt to connect.

Comment: `1.` Port 7342 isn't a standard (well known) port so why not just port forward it directly rather than translating the port from 11001 to 7342? You're just adding unneeded complexity. `2.` Are you using HTTPS and specifying the port in your browser when you access the site? `https://x.x.x.x:11001`

Comment: Ok, I have tried that and it still isnt working, and yes I am

Comment: Try setting the protocol to TCP instead of TCP/UDP. Also, is there a corresponding firewall rule allowing the access (Open Ports)?

Comment: @AlexWalker-Ingham, I see you have multiple wans, so make sure you are using the right wan ip for testing. And what is your PRTG web server's (192.168.1.21 server) default gateway? It should be the firewall, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Hello, You have solved the issue! It was using the other WAN as the gateway rather than the one I was trying to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the firewall port forwarding rule looks good, the other important thing to check is, if the network configuration is correct. For the port forwarding to work, the PRTG server's default gateway should be the firewall. Since you have multiple WAN, so check and make sure the Server is configured with the right gateway ip.